# How to write a bash script to copy files from one base to another base location

Tags: bash

I have a bash script I'm trying to write
I have 2 base directories:

- ./tmp/serve/
- ./src/

I want to go through all the directories in ./tmp and copy the *.html files into the same folder path in ./src

i.e
if I have a html file in ./tmp/serve/**app/components/help/** help.html -->
copy to ./src/**app/components/help/** And recursively do this for all subdirectories in ./tmp/

*NOTE: the folder structures should exist so just need to copy them only. If it doesn't then hopefully it could create the folder for me (not what I want) but with GIT I can track these folders to manually handle those loose html files.*

I got as far as

```
echo $(find . -name "*.html")\n
```

But not sure how to actually extract the file path with pwd and do what I need to, maybe it's not a one liner and needs to be done with some vars.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
for i in `echo $(find /tmp/ -name "*.html")\n
do
    cp -r $i /src/app/components/help/
done
```

going so far to create the directories would take some more time for me.
I'll try to do it on my own and see if I come up with something
but for argument sake if you do run `pwd` and get a response the pseudo code for that:

1. pwd
2. get response
3. if that directory does not exist in src create that directory
4. copy all the original directories contents into the new folder at /src/$newfolder
   (possibly running two for loops, one to check the directory tree, and then one to go through each original directory, copying all the html files)

Comment: Hey, yeah so the destination of the copy should be based on the path of the source as mentioned in original description. Your pseudo code was basically what I had started to think about but based on the other suggestions actually I got to where I needed without the pwd command as find can extract the file path and a regex can be applied from there.

Answer (score 0):

You [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) to loop the output from your find command and create the destination directory(ies) and then copy the file(s):

```
#!/bin/bash

# accept first parameters to script as src_dir and dest values or 
# simply use default values if no parameter(s) passed
src_dir=${1:-/tmp/serve}
dest=${2-src}

while read -r orig_path ; do
    # To replace the first occurrence of a pattern with a given string, 
    # use ${parameter/pattern/string}
    dest_path="${orig_path/tmp\/serve/${dest}}"

    # Use dirname to remove the filename from the destination path
    # and create the destination directory.
    dest_dir=$(dirname "${dest_path}")
    mkdir -p "${dest_dir}"
    
    cp "${orig_path}" "${dest_path}"
done < <(find "${src_dir}" -name '*.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

This script copy .html files from src directory to des directory (create the subdirectory if they do not exist)

Find the files, then remove the src directory name and copy them into the destination directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `echo $(find src/ -name "*.html")`
do
  file=$(echo $i | sed 's/src\///g')
  cp -r --parents $i des
done
```

Comment: I actually solved this in the end because the answers didn't come in when I needed them and resolved this with the help of some online sources about bash commands.

Comment: In essense I've done what you've done, but perhaps a lot less elegant. Either case, I do a for loop on the find command and some regex to get the destination as you've done. 
     `[[ $file =~ 'app.*' ]]
     cp $file src/"${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"`
Arguably didn't know about sed but that's doing what I've done in one line.
Will keep what I have cos it works but this is probably more bash best practice :P

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you must use `bash` constructs or not, but here is a GNU `tar` solution (if you use GNU tar), which IMHO is the best way to handle this situation because all the metadata for the files (permissions, etc.) are preserved:

```bash
find ./tmp/serve -name '*.html' -type f -print0 | tar --null -T - -c | tar -x -v -C ./src --strip-components=3
```

This finds all the `.html` files (`-type f`) in the `./tmp/serve` directory and prints them nul-terminated (`-print0`), then sends these filenames via `stdin` to `tar` as nul-terminated literals (`--null`) for inclusion (`-T -`), creating (`-c`) an archive which is then sent to another `tar` instance which extracts (`-x`) the archive printing its contents along the way (optional: `-v`), changing directory to the destination (`-C ./src`) before commencing and stripping (`--strip-components=3`) the `./tmp/serve/` prefix from the files. (You could also `cd ./tmp/serve` beforehand, using `find .` instead, and change `-C` to `../../src`.)

Comment: write yeah that's handy to know about premissions ... not needed in my case as it's a local script I need to be able to just port a few files over that don't have any complex prem rules.